# SAT MATH Circle Geometry

Tags: circles

How many points may be contained in the intersection of 2 distinct circles?

The answer is 0, 1 and 2 points. I don't get why it could be 0 points when two circles are intersecting.

Comment: answer: 2. Draw two intersecting circles .

Comment: @DeepSea: Not necessarily. ... in mathematics the intersection of two things can definitely sometimes be the empty set, so no points in common.

Comment: 2 distinct circles can intersect in 1 or 2 points

Comment: I think the question was too ambiguous, but as Jose answered, concentric circles could be counted for $0$ points.

Comment: The question is not ambiguous.  Take note, it asks:  "How many points *may be* contained in the intersection of $2$ distinct circles?" and **NOT** "How many points may be contained in the intersection of $2$ distinct *intersecting* circles?"

Comment: The problem is asking how many different amount of points can fit. If you draw 2 circle intersecting, it has an intersecting point, but it doesn't need to be counted. $0$ points could "fit" in this region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem clearly asks:

> "How many points may be contained in the intersection of 2 distinct circles?"

And thus, the assumption that the circles are actually intersecting in all three cases is wrong.

- There can be $0$ points in the intersection of two distinct circles, if they are not intersecting. This implies that there is a distance between any point on circle $A$ and any point on circle $B$.
- There is $1$ point of intersection, when there is only one point $P$ that is included in both circles.
- There are $2$ points of intersection, when only two points are common to both circles.

See the image below for clarifications:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**No points of intersection**

[image: No points of intersection]

**One point of intersection**

[image: One point of intersection]

**Two points of intersection**

[image: Two points of intersection]

Comment: but in case 1 and 2 the the circles are not intersect with each other

Comment: @k.Vijay, please see Ted Shifrin's and Lê Đức Minh's comments above.

Comment: It is possible to give examples from analytic geometry where these cases become apparent and clear.  I will edit those examples into this answer when time permits.